# Overload of std:find function

Tags: c++, stl

I tried to overload the std::find function, in this way:

```
include <list>
include <string>
include "Marker.h"

namespace Test {



    class MarkerContainer {

    private:
        std::list<Marker*> list;
        double end_t;
        inline bool exists(std::list<Marker*> *input_list, Marker* check);
    public:

        MarkerContainer();
        MarkerContainer(double end_time);
        bool addMarker(Marker* input);
        double computeBeatTime(double sample_t);
        double computeSampleTime(double beat_t);    
        void printAll();

    };

    }


    std::list<Ableton::Marker*>::iterator std::find(std::list<Ableton::Marker*>::iterator first, std::list<Ableton::Marker*>::iterator last, Ableton::Marker* value){
            for ( ;first!=last; first++) if ( **first==*value ) break;
            return first;

        }
```

But I catch this compiler error:

> Out-of-line definition of 'find' does not match any declaration in
>   namespace 'std' in /Users/.../MarkerContainer.h

I hope I did some stupid mistake and what I would like to do is simple.. any idea ?

Thanks in advance!
Pietro

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't permit you to create functions in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: in general yes, but you are allowed to specialize. (Not that this Q is specializing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't allowed to overload `find`. You are allowed to specialize templates in the `std` namespace, but in this case it's far simpler to use `find_if` with a dereferencing functor.

```
// Create DerefEquality comparison (I'll try to come back later and write it).
container_type::iterator iter = find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), DerefEquality(item_to_find));
```

Comment: ok! I understood! For guys with my same problem see :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload a function like this: you need to define the overload in an appropriate namespace. You need to open namespace `std` at global scope. Specifically with namespace `std` I don't think you are allowed to do this. Otherwise this would work.

That said, I think you should look at using `std::find_if()` with a suitable predicate instead of using your hand-crafted approach:

```
auto it = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
                       [=](Abelton::Marker* el)->bool { return *el == *check; });
```